# Add search criteria in the Finder in Catalina

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, catalina, search

I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15 inches, mid-2015) with a 2.8 GHz Intel quad core i7 processor, now running macOS Catalina 10.15.3.

Before the upgrade, I could do a search as follows. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to open a Finder window; select what I want to search (this Mac, recent files, etc); press the Plus Sign to add criteria (such as extension, title, type of file, etc). After the upgrade, there is no Plus Sign. All I can do is search all occurrences of whatever I type.

How do I add search criteria like I did before?

Comment: I have macOS Catalina and it's visible. Perhaps it's worth trying to remove the Finder preferences plist and relaunch finder.

Comment: There is no finder plist file in my preferences, as far as I can tell. That said, it is difficult to find a file by name and file extension without being able to add that as a search criteria. I notice that there is no com.apple.finder folder. There are folders that start with that name followed by other things.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this as well on my Catalina MBP. For some reason it defaults to hidden. To make it visible click on the Action button (looks like a gear) then `Show Search Criteria`.

[image]